# Why can't I compare a vba string type and a SQL short text type?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table with a short text field and a function that return a string type. When I compare the field to the returned value of the function a  get the following error:

**Data type mismatch on criteria expression.**

---

**Tables**

[image]

**Query**

```
UPDATE myTable
SET clean = ""
WHERE trimWebAddress(webAddress) in (
SELECT domain FROM genericDomains)
```

**Function**

```
Public Function trimWebAddress(ByVal address As String) As String
    Dim cleanAddress As String

    If IsNull(address) = False Then
        cleanAddress = address
        If InStr(1, cleanAddress, "no_domain_available") = 1 Then
            cleanAddress = ""
        ElseIf InStr(1, cleanAddress, "https://") = 1 Then
            cleanAddress = Replace(cleanAddress, "https://", "")
        Else
            cleanAddress = Replace(cleanAddress, "http://", "")
        End If
        If InStr(1, cleanAddress, "www.") = 1 Then
            cleanAddress = Replace(cleanAddress, "www.", "")
        End If
        If InStr(1, cleanAddress, "/") > 0 Then
            cleanAddress = Left(cleanAddress, InStr(1, cleanAddress, "/") - 1)
        End If
    Else
        cleanAddress = ""
    End If
    trimWebAddress = cleanAddress
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have *Null* values in your data.

You can modify like this:

```
Public Function trimWebAddress(ByVal address As Variant) As String

    Dim cleanAddress As String

    If Nz(address) <> "" Then
        cleanAddress = address
        If InStr(1, cleanAddress, "no_domain_available") = 1 Then
            cleanAddress = ""
        ElseIf InStr(1, cleanAddress, "https://") = 1 Then
            cleanAddress = Replace(cleanAddress, "https://", "")
        Else
            cleanAddress = Replace(cleanAddress, "http://", "")
        End If
        If InStr(1, cleanAddress, "www.") = 1 Then
            cleanAddress = Replace(cleanAddress, "www.", "")
        End If
        If InStr(1, cleanAddress, "/") > 0 Then
            cleanAddress = Left(cleanAddress, InStr(1, cleanAddress, "/") - 1)
        End If
    End If

    ' Prevent zero-length output.
    If cleanAddress = "" Then
        cleanAddress = "NotToBeFound"
    End If

    trimWebAddress = cleanAddress

End Function
```

Or you may have to update to Null if zero-length string is not allowed:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET clean = Null
WHERE trimWebAddress(webAddress) in (
SELECT domain FROM genericDomains)
```

Comment: Yes. I also ran an update query like the one in my question, but without the trimWebAddress function, just some other where clause, and it worked.

Comment: Perhaps the SQL doesn't like the zero-length output of the function. See edit for a way to work around that.